# Boost serialization assertion fail

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, assert, assertion

I use boost's binary serialization and it worked well until now. I have `std::list` of pointers to serialize for output (oarchive) but serialization fails inside object's serialize() function with MSVC's dialog:

`R6010 -abort() has been called`

and such string is printed into console window:

`Assertion failed: 0 == static_cast<int>(t) || 1 == static_cast<int>(t), file c:\program files\boost\boost_1_44\boost\archive\basic_binary_oprimitive.hpp, line 91`

what does it mean?

Project is pretty big, sources are distributed so I cannot post it's code here, but I tried to simulate this error within simple project - there it works fine what is strange.

P.S. I use **boost 1.44** with MSVC2010EE on Windows XP. When I click "*retry*" on "*Debug Error!*" window debugger shows arrow on the code line **next** to serialization `archive << myList;` line - I mean it seems like error occurred at some destructor or something.
When I make changes inside objects serialize() function - they will be applied just when I rebuild whole project (clean before compiling) - but if I just compile it (where IDE shows that all sources which include changed header are recompiled) - no changes will happen at runtime since last version (I tried with printf()) - that's strange.
Could I occasionally set some critical definitions or something?

Comment: difficult to help without any code. Can you boil this down to a small reproducible example and include it here?

Comment: If you go up the call stack a bit eventually you will get to the point where you can figure out what caused the problem, e.g,. which field in a struct

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line in question says:

```
// trap usage of invalid uninitialized boolean which would
// otherwise crash on load.
```

It looks like at some point you are trying to serialize a `bool` that hasn't been initialized.  Without further code we can't help you find which one.

Comment: There is really bool! Just before crash!

Comment: Hmm, what must I do then?
#include <boost/serialization/bool.hpp>  ? - there is no such file.

Comment: That means you are just declaring the variable `bool tmp;` without initializing it: `bool tmp = 0;`

Comment: A similar problem appears on certain platforms (e.g., MacOSX) when floats are not initialized.  If you plant to serialize a variable, check to see whether you have given it a default value in the constructor.

Comment: Additional information according to karlphillip's post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243990/strange-bool-values